# Add line breaks to Rails text email without double spacing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I add line breaks to a plain text email in Rails 4 without adding extra spacing?

For example:

Email template: email.text.erb

```
Thank you for contacting<%= "\r\n" %>
us today.  We appreciate<%= "\r\n" %>
your business.
```

This is what the email looks like:

```
Thank you for contacting

us today.  We appreciate

your business.
```

I want it to look like this (single spacing):

```
Thank you for contacting
us today.  We appreciate
your business.
```

I've tried with and without the <%= "\r\n" %> entries but nothing works.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using SendGrid to deliver emails.  I just discovered that they have a setting to automatically convert text emails into html.  When I turn this setting off in SendGrid, the formatting in email.text.erb appears in the email unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to write `<%= "\r\n" %>`, just

```
Thank you for contacting
us today.  We appreciate
your business.
```

Comment: Okey, what about to put text at one line and place `<%= "\n" %>`?